# Who is charged for Github Actions minutes?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Are GitHub Action minutes deducted from the quota of the repo owner or the user who pushes the commit to github.com?

I'm working on a free software project that uses a Github Actions workflow to automate a continuous integration pipeline. The repo is tied to my account, but I'm debating whether or not I want to grant push access to it for another developer or if I should have them fork it.

Github grants a free 2,000 "minutes" per month per user (fine print redefines "2,000 minutes" to a total of "200 minutes" per month for MacOS, but whatever).

If another github user pushes commits to my repo that trigger Github Actions, are those minutes subtracted from my quota or that user's quota? And how does this work for repos in a github organization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the page where you can find all information about how Github actions are billed. https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-billing-and-payments-on-github/about-billing-for-github-actions

> GitHub charges usage to the account that owns the repository where the workflow is run

I hope that answers your question